# React JS inherit functionally to several components

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with functionally, let's say if you click on it, it does: `alert("Hello World");`

But now, let's say I want several components to have the same functionality, and these components can be expanded in the future, how can I do that in good way?

I thought about HOC but then I would have to decide which element to use, for example `<div>` but I want it to be generic so I could decide to put inside whatever element I need.

Comment: this is a perfect use case for creating your own hook

Comment: @azium what is the alternative if I use Class based components?

Comment: add the alert functionality to `this.props.children`

Comment: aka use render props  https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Comment: Thanks this article has great explanation!

Comment: @Dorki it is not an article, they are the official docs of react.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases, I would suggest creating [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) or [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) to reuse functionality. For your example, however, you could just have a very simple file:

```
// alert.js
const Alert = msg => ({
  onClick: () => alert(msg),
})

export default Alert
```

And use it like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div { ...Alert('Hello World') }>
      click me
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, could you add @azium link about how to do that in Class based component? this link: https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html so others could also see other options to implement that

Answer (score 1):

[Here is](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-lehmann-qxk2x?file=/src/App.js) a potential solution I came up with that uses React's createClass function. You could rework to handle many (i.e. unlimited) elements within that main element, so that each child could have it's own tag, too